# What happens if I don't specify type parameter of a generic superclass

Tags: java

Eclipse complains if I have a subclass that extends a generic super class.  So say I have an extension of ArrayList but don't specify the type parameter of ArrayList like so:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList {
    ...
}
```

I see a warning:

> ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList
>   should be parameterized

It makes sense that ArrayList would be parameterized with `<T>`, but what exactly can go wrong here?

Comment: *why is this only a warning? What can go wrong here?* Those sound like opposite questions.

Comment: Every time a programmer uses a generic type without a type parameter, a kitten dies.

Comment: removed the "why is this only a warning?" as it was more of a side question

Comment: Same as usual: you break type safety. For example, you might call `add("foo");` from within the class.